# How to remove supervision from my iPad imposed by my school that I’m not attending anymore

Tags: ipad, mobile-device-management

My iPad is supervised by my school, but I’m not at that school anymore. Does anyone know how to remove the supervision without a factory reset?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to contact the school to have them remove the supervision from the iPad. They can do that remotely, but any apps, etc. that you got from the school will end up being deleted, as an erase of all contents and settings is required.

You cannot remove the supervision yourself.